# Mobile menu with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am adding a select menu on my site, this is a test page http://ww2.hawaiidiscount.com/HawaiiActivities/tabid/562/Default.aspx 
See how the long menu on the right becomes a select-like box when you see it with a small screen. The issue is that when I mouse over the menu on mobile the menu list shows up and then if I don't click on any of the links the menu stays expanded. How can I fix that so if you click away from the menu it will hide?

Here is a screenshot how the menu appears when I touch it with iPhone - http://kaniamea.com/photo.PNG

The menu is expanded and doesn't collapse.

My code is:

```
<script>
$('.nav-list-2 > li a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    });​
</script>

<style>



@media (min-width:601px) and (max-width:2024px) {
.current {display:none;}
    }

@media (min-width:200px) and (max-width:600px) {
    .nav-list-right {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 40px;
    }   
    .nav-list-right ul {
        width: 180px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
        background: #fff url(images/icon-menu.png) no-repeat 10px 11px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
    .nav-list-right li {
        display: none; /* hide all <li> items */
        margin: 0;
    }
    .nav-list-right .current {
        display: block; /* show only current <li> item */
    }
    .nav-list-right a {
        display: block;

        text-align: left;
    }
    .nav-list-right .current a {
        background: none;
        color: #666;
    }

    /* on nav-list-right hover */
    .nav-list-right ul:hover {
        background-image: none;
    }
    .nav-list-right ul:hover li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
    }


    /* right nav-list-right */
    .nav-list-right.right ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }

    /* center nav-list-right */
    .nav-list-right.center ul {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -90px;
    }

ul.nav-list-2 li a {
    padding: 2px 1px 1px 10px !important;
    background: transparent url("http://ww2.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/_default/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/yellow-nav-bullet.png") no-repeat scroll left 7px ;
}

ul.nav-list-2 li a:hover {
    padding: 2px 1px 1px 10px !important;
    background: transparent url("http://ww2.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/_default/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/yellow-nav-bullet.png") no-repeat scroll left 7px ;
}

.current {
    padding: 7px 0px 0px 30px !important;
            background: url("http://ww2.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/icon-check.png") no-repeat 10px 7px;
                border-bottom: none !important;

}

</style>
```

Comment: How are you "mousing over the menu" on mobile? Do you simply mean you are shrinking the page?

Comment: By clicking the first link in the menu, next to the menu icon.

Comment: I'm shrinking the page and mousing over it and I am not getting this behavior. What OS and Browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. It works fine on Desktop but not on mobile.

Comment: What is the context of mobile? This is what I'm asking. You typically don't use a mouse with a mobile device.

Comment: When you click the mobile icon with a mobile device the menu expands. The problem is it doesn't collapse once it is expanded. That's what I am trying to fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98524/discussion-between-sinistralis-and-parlanchina).